# Knockout.js Google Maps Infowindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I am on a project building a app with Knockout.js and the Google Maps API. I am having trouble getting the infowindow content to populate when clicking on the markers. I have searched for a solution with my code and have not found anytning that works. I feel like I am close and would like to know if anyone can give me a push.

```
var map, infoWindow, marker, html;

var content;
var markerInfo;

var locations = [
  {name: 'Acquerello', latlng: {lat: 37.79161, lng: -122.42143}},
  {name: 'Cordon Bleu Vietnamese Restaurant', latlng: {lat: 37.79088, lng: -122.42022}}, 
  {name: 'Dunya', latlng: {lat: 37.79168, lng: -122.42113}}, 
  {name: 'Rangoon Ruby Burmese Cuisine', latlng: {lat: 37.79175, lng: -122.42079}}, 
  {name: 'Ti Piacera', latlng: {lat: 37.79079, lng: -122.42098}}
];

//tells the view model what to do when a change occurs
function Location(value) {
  this.name = ko.observable(value.name);
  this.latlng = ko.observable(value.latlng);
};

//ViewModel
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.markers = [];
  markerInfo = [];
  content = "Something goes here!"
  //experimental code begin
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    markerInfo.push(new Location(locations[i].name));
  }
  self.loc = ko.observableArray(markerInfo);

  self.useForEach = function() {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.loc(), function(item) {
      content = item.name();
    });
  }
  //experimental code end

  //copies the values of locations and stores them in sortedLocations(); observableArray
  self.sortedLocations = ko.observableArray(locations);

  //Adds new markers at each location in the locations Array
  self.sortedLocations().forEach(function(location) {
    html = location;
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location.latlng,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    location.marker = marker;

    //Pushes each marker into the markers array
    this.markers.push(marker);
  });

  //Map info windows to each item in the markers array
  self.markers.map(function(info, location) {
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
    });
    //add click event to each marker to open info window
    info.addListener('click', function(location, html) {
      html = '<div>' + content + '</div>';
      infoWindow.setContent(html);
      infoWindow.open(map, this), 
        info.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)
      setTimeout(function() {
        info.setAnimation(null)
      }, 2000);
    });
  });

  //click on item in list view 
  self.listViewClick = function(location) {
    if(location.name) {
      location.marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      infoWindow.open(map, location.marker);
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      location.marker.setAnimation(null);
    }, 2000);
  };

  //stores user input
  self.query = ko.observable('');

  //Filter through observableArray and filter results using knockouts utils.arrayFilter();
  self.search = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.sortedLocations(), function(listResult) {
      return listResult.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.query().toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });
  });
};

//create instance of a map from the Google Maps API
//Grab the reference to the "map" id to display the map
//Set the map options object properties
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 37.7915039, 
      lng: -122.4207347
    },
    zoom: 18
  });

};

$(document).ready(function() {
  initMap();
  ko.applyBindings(ViewModel());
});

<!-- here is the html portion of the work -->
<div id="map" class="flex-video">

    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>

<input type="search" placeholder="Search Location" size="35" data-bind="textInput: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'">

<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'itemsTmpl', foreach: search }">
    </tbody>
    <script id="itemsTmpl" type="text/html">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p data-bind="text: $data.name, click: listViewClick"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </script>
</table>
```

Comment: You are missing the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) in `applyBindings`. Change it to `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());` If it still doesn't work, check the console for any errors.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Click [here](http://support.prez.is/2G0p2D3i3m18) to see the error I get in the console. It's an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' undefined. I am also left with one marker instead of all five.

Comment: I'm willing to wager it's your call to `this.markers.push(marker);` the scope of `this` probably changed. Which is why you used `self`. Try changing that to `self.markers.push(marker);`

Comment: Scrapped the code and rebuilt it and found problems with the code that I fixed along the way. Thank you for your feedback. Everything works up to this point. All the banging of my head paid off. My unfinished work is [here](https://github.com/heyharv/neighborhood-map).